# Custom redirect based on user role in rails 5 with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Its been some time since I've worked with rails and I am jumping into a "project" for a company I work for..

Essentially what I am trying to do is redirect a user who logs in to the app to a specific page upon login..

For example an admin user will be redirected to an admin dashboard, an owner will be redirected to an owner dashboard and a driver to a driver dashboard..

Ive done this in the past using a single view and then filling it with `elseif` statements. But I found that to make my code look clunky and slow the app down.

I cant seem to find any docs (probably because I've been out of the game so long) on how to redirect to a specific url based on a user role.. Is this even possible? if so would someone be willing to share some resources as I am reaally struggling in this department.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: Implemented `ApplicationController` method to find user role and redirect to appropriate page.

so I have added a few lines of code to my `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.role == "dispatch"
    dashboard_dispatch_path
  else
    root_path
  end
end

end
```

when I try to load the page, the url in the browser changes to the proper url, however I get the following error:

[image: Better Errors screenshot]

the stack trace from rails server:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-01 12:10:58 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LJSAbgb3spFs0kEgFMYa40m2TZmZvH7weq53ciuGZAO07SUBgTHdxYTH0+MjRuYZIi+9++zIjnJP2rllVws5DA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"swixxxx@xxxxxltd.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "swixxxx@xxxxxxltd.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "sign_in_count" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["current_sign_in_at", "2018-04-01 18:10:58.835548"], ["sign_in_count", 2], ["updated_at", "2018-04-01 18:10:58.836544"], ["id", 2]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/dispatch
Completed 302 Found in 150ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)


Started GET "/dashboard/dispatch" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-01 12:10:58 -0600

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0):
  app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:5:in `dispatch'

Started POST "/__better_errors/cda7f553a5c61c4b/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-01 12:10:58 -0600
```

EDIT 2: adds Controller Code:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def admin
  end

  def dispatch
  end

  def owner
  end

  def driver
  end

  def client
  end

  def guest
  end

end
```

Comment: What determines an admin? You just need to have an elsif statement for `redirect_to`, based off the role.

Comment: @gwalshington an enum in the user model thats assigned when an admin generates a new user role is determined

Comment: @gwalshington so would the best way to handle this be to create a custom devise sessions controller and place the redirects in there?

Comment: Take a look at some after sign in method, there is one for devise in docs. There you can test for `current_admin.present?` or `current_owner.present?` and use the redirect_to statement. Should be `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` in application controller.

Comment: @h_matze_h that was what i was looking for!!! thanks.

Comment: Right - just like above, you can redirect depending on the user. And then  on the admin page you can also have something like `before_action :authenticate_admin`, and in that function, if authentication fails, send to the regular user home page.

Comment: I updated this question with an error I've hit and not sure what I've done here..

Comment: Think an end missing in the dashboard controller.

Comment: @h_matze_h just checked all ends are present. nothing was modified in that controller.

Comment: Maybe redirect instead of return. Sry have no other idea. :(

`redirect_to`